# What is a regular expression that will remove all "function foo() { ... }" and show other content?

Tags: javascript, regex

That is, given a Javascript file, this regular expression can show only the "immediate execution" of code, removing all the function definitions in the form of

```
function foo() {
  ...
}
```

Or can regular expression find the "matching `{ }`" because there can many nested `{ }`

Comment: Basically you want to *decompile* an existing function, and extract its function body? If it's so, although there are some limitations, it's possible...

Comment: oh actually to remove all functions and its body

Answer (score 2):

There is no such regular expression. The reason is based on theory of automata and grammars. The language

```
function foo() { ... }
```

can be generated by context free grammar, but not by regular grammar. For more info have a look at [wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is too complex a language to be reliably parsed using a regular expression.  There's not just the problem you mentioned about the nested braces; there's also the fact that pretty much anything in a string should be ignored, that there's at least two ways to define a function, and a bunch of other issues.

Also, what would you do about `function() { alert("Hello!"); }();`?  That's a function, but it executes immediately.

Basically, you'd need a javascript interpreter or debugger of some kind in order to see what runs and what doesn't.